# Assign Font From TComboBox D7

Tags: delphi

Delphi v7

Let me preface my remedial question by saying that I am not a real programer. I am a Deputy Sheriff and I write an occasional project to help us do what we do.

My current project contains several TDBRichEdit controls. I have assigned various formatting processes to toolbar buttons. I would like to be able to change the RichEdit font using a ComboBox. The combobox is populated with the font list, but it does not affect the font of the TDBRichEdit control. I have been trying to figure this out for over a week and I cannot see the problem.

This is what I have done:

**Form OnCreate procedure**

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
PageControl1.ActivePage:= TabSheet1;
  GetFontNames;
  SelectionChange(Self);
  CurrText.Name := DefFontData.Name;
  CurrText.Size := -MulDiv(DefFontData.Height, 72, Screen.PixelsPerInch);
  end;
```

**Form Selection Change**

```
procedure TForm1.SelectionChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ActiveControl is TDBRichEdit then
    with ActiveControl as
    TdbRichEdit do  begin
  try
    Ctrlupdating := True;

    Size.Text := IntToStr(SelAttributes.Size);
    cmbFont.Text := SelAttributes.Name; 
finally
    Ctrlupdating := False;
  end;
end;
end;
```

**Functions (Except for the "ActiveControl part these are not my functions and I don't have enough knowledge to completely understand them.)**

```
Function TForm1.CurrText: TTextAttributes;
begin
if ActiveControl is TDBRichEdit then
    with ActiveControl as
    TdbRichEdit do  begin
  if SelLength > 0 then Result := SelAttributes
  else Result := DefAttributes;
end;
end;

function EnumFontsProc(var LogFont: TLogFont; var TextMetric: TTextMetric;
  FontType: Integer; Data: Pointer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  TStrings(Data).Add(LogFont.lfFaceName);
  Result := 1;
end;
```

**OnDraw event of the combobox**

```
procedure TForm1.cmbFontDrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
 begin
 with (Control as TComboBox).Canvas do
  begin
    Font.Name := Screen.Fonts.Strings[Index];
    FillRect(Rect) ;
    TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, PChar(Screen.Fonts.Strings[Index]));

  end;
  end;
```

**OnChange event for the combobox**

```
procedure TForm1.cmbFontChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
if Ctrlupdating then Exit;
  CurrText.Name := cmbFont.Items[cmbFont.ItemIndex];
end;
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: I really meant what I said in the comment above. Some of your old questions have excellent answers that should be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you try to modify the text attributes in this code:

```
procedure TForm1.cmbFontChange(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  if Ctrlupdating then Exit;
  CurrText.Name := cmbFont.Items[cmbFont.ItemIndex];
end;
```

When this code executes, ActiveControl will be cmbFont. Now look at CurrText.

```
if ActiveControl is TDBRichEdit then
  with ActiveControl as TdbRichEdit do 
  begin
    if SelLength > 0 then
      Result := SelAttributes
    else 
      Result := DefAttributes;
  end;
```

So, the first if block will not be entered.

In fact your function appears not to assign anything to Result in this case. You must always assign to Result. The compiler will tell you this when you enable warnings and hints.

Instead of using ActiveControl you should specify the rich edit instance directly. I don't know how your form is arranged, but you'll need to use some other means to work out which rich edit control the change is to be applied to. Perhaps based on the active page of the page control.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the combobox working. My code is probably very awkward, but it works.  Thank you for your help. I would not have been able to solve this problem without it.

I wrote a separate function for each of the richedit contols. With FormCreate I had to add lines for each of the functions

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
PageControl1.ActivePage:= TabSheet1;
  GetFontNames;
  SelectionChange(Self);
  **CurrText.Name := DefFontData.Name;
  CurrText.Size := -MulDiv(DefFontData.Height, 72, Screen.PixelsPerInch);**
  end;
```

In **SelectionChange** I had to make a call to the **PARAGRAPH** attributes of the rich edit control. I was not able to do that collectively. I addressed the rich edit control **“reProc”** only. The others seem to work fine with that one line. I would like to understand that one.

**Form Selection Change**
    procedure TForm1.SelectionChange(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      if ActiveControl is TDBRichEdit then
    with **reProc.Paragraph** do begin
      try do  begin

You gave me the idea. I was not able to address all the richedit controls collectively, so I wrote a function for each of the richedit controls separately.

```
function TForm1.CurrText: TTextAttributes;
begin
 if reProc.SelLength > 0 then Result := reProc.SelAttributes
  else Result := **reProc.DefAttributes;**
```

For the **OnChange** event for the combobox I had to add lines for each of the functions

```
procedure TForm1.cmbFontChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if Ctrlupdating then Exit;
  **CurrText.Name := cmbFont.Items[cmbFont.ItemIndex];**
end;
```